# Can I limit "git clean -fd" to a single directory?

Tags: git

Is it possible to limit the scope of `git clean -fd` to a single directory? Ideally I would be searching for something like
`git clean -fd --include=./delete_only/files_and_dirs_below_me/*`

Background:
I've got a bash update script for my web projects. The workflow is as follows:

1. On prod env: export current configuration to git tracked directory `config/sync`
2. On prod: git push & commit
3. On dev env: git pull
4. On dev: import configuration from `config/sync`
5. On dev: do updates
6. On dev: export config
7. On dev: git push & commit
8. On prod: git pull
9. On Prod: import config

The problem is that "export current config" creates and/or deletes a bunch of `.yml` files in the git tracked `config/sync` directory. E.g. if I disable module `foo` on prod env, config export will delete the corresponding `config/sync/foo.yml` file. But if that specific module was enabled on dev too, the file does already exist on dev, and does not get deleted after step 3, resulting into an invalid config import at step 4 with module `foo` still enabled.

I now would like to add steps
 3.5 git clean -fd --include=./config/sync/*
and
 8.5 git clean -fd --include=./config/sync/*
in a way that is safe enough for an unattended script.

Some years ago I had a very bad experience with a failed maintenaince script doing basically `cd some_dir && rm -rf` (guess what happened when the remote server was unreachable...) and I'm trying to be more careful this time.

Comment: A simple `git clean -fd config/sync` should do the trick. Or am I missing something? (You can test with `git clean -fdn` which performs a dry run.)

Comment: Damn, this is maliciously easy... I've wasted hours trying to do it with exclude patterns. Thank you, that was way to obvious for me  :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git clean` takes zero or more path arguments. According to the [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean):

> If any optional `<path>...` arguments are given, only those paths are affected.

So a simple `git clean -fd config/sync` should do the trick.